# What should we put in our FAQ?

Tags: discussion

The moderators are now able to edit [the FAQ.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq)  What should we put there?

Logistics: Each answer should contain a FAQ and its answer.  The question is community wiki, so you can edit answers in order to improve them.  Use comments for discussion.

Answer (score 4):

### What kind of questions can I ask here?

We welcome questions related to building, maintaining, and repairing a home.

This includes:

- General construction & related trades (framing, electrical, plumbing, HVAC, drywall/plaster, painting, etc)
- Patios, decks, porches, and fences
- Sheds, garages, greenhouses, and barns
- Retaining walls
- Installation and repair of major appliances
- Finding, selecting, and working with contractors and architects
- Building codes and electrical codes
- Lawn and yard maintenance, including trees & shrubs (but not specialized gardening, see separate FAQ)
- Pest control
- Cleaning a specific item
- Getting a general idea of the cost of a project (but not solicitations for contractor bids for a particular job)
- Stormwater management, drainage issues, catchment basins, septic systems, and retaining walls
- Driveways and sidewalks
- Energy efficiency improvements

Comment: What about fencing? (The kind that goes around your yard, not the sport.) I can't decide if that should go with 'patios, deck, and porches' or 'lawn and yard maintenance.'

Comment: @Doresoom: Thanks, added with patios.

Answer (score 2):

### What information should I include in my question?

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to provide clear and concise details concerning the project.  This includes:

- Country/region where the project will take place.
- Pictures, diagrams, or illustrations
- Manufacturers, vendors, model numbers (where appropriate).

[This question needs some work but I think you get the basic idea]